# How mass of a nucleus can be measured?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

I know that mass of an atom can be measured using mass spectrometer, but how mass of a nucleus can be measured? simply by subtracting total electron mass of that atom? or there are other professional ways?

The point of my question is how mass of dineutron observed in 2012 could be measured?

Comment: You can strip all the electrons off a regular nucleus. For the a dineutron I don’t know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State of the art mass measurements are performed using Penning [traps](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-nucl-102711-094939). There is (with pretty high confidence) no bound dineutron.

Penning traps only work for charged particles, but there are traps (magnetic, magento-optical (MOTT), or all-optical) for neutral particles. Also, less accurate masses can be obtained by measuring the Q-values (the energy released) in nuclear reactions. For example, if a di-neutron existed, you could measure the mass from the energy balance in $\gamma+T\to p+(nn)$, where $T$ is the triton.

Comment: In 2012, a ground state dineutron was observed from decay of Be-16 (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.102501), but the problem i refereed to is how we can measure mass of bound neutrons (it doesn't matter they exist or not).

Comment: @Elsayed  This paper is about two-neutron radioactivity, not the formation of a di-neutron (the two neutrons that are emitted are not bound). Added a postscript to my answer.

Comment: assume they exist professor, who could we measure their mass?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to collect a very large, very pure, and accurately known number of atoms and weigh it. Divide the weight of collection by the number of atoms in it and you get the weight of a single atom. Subtract the weight of the electrons (which is small) and you have the weight of the nucleus.

How to collect an accurately known number of atoms? In the field of electrochemistry, you can figure out how many electrons get pulled free from an atom when a certain electrochemical reaction takes place. You can then measure that electron flow as the reaction proceeds and relate how many electrons were liberated by how many grams of those atoms. Then you know how many atoms there are in a gram of that material.

Comment: Your answer is very useful, from your answer i think you have some experience in such field, but how could we measure dineutron mass for instance professor?

Comment: I have never heard of a dineutron!